# Karaf bundle using ch.qos.logback , log4j org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ReflectionUtil

Tags: log4j, bundle, logback, apache-karaf

I have an osgi 6.0.0 project which uses logback and slf4j.

Currently I am implementing a bundle which depends on an external jar which uses
org.apache.logging.log4j

during the command line execution the bundle my karaf console freezes by displaying this error :

Exception in thread "Karaf local console user karaf" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ReflectionUtil
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.(ThrowableProxy.java:145)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.(ThrowableProxy.java:125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.MutableLogEvent.getThrownProxy(MutableLogEvent.java:338)
    at org.ops4j.pax.logging.log4j2.internal.PaxLoggingEventImpl.getThrowableStrRep(PaxLoggingEventImpl.java:76)
    at org.apache.karaf.log.core.internal.KarafLogEvent.(KarafLogEvent.java:45)
    at org.apache.karaf.log.core.internal.LogServiceImpl.doAppend(LogServiceImpl.java:177)
    at org.ops4j.pax.logging.log4j2.internal.PaxAppenderProxy.doAppend(PaxAppenderProxy.java:65)
    at org.ops4j.pax.logging.log4j2.appender.PaxOsgiAppender.append(PaxOsgiAppender.java:82)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:448)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:433)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:417)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:403)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:63)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:146)
    at org.ops4j.pax.logging.log4j2.internal.PaxLoggerImpl.doLog0(PaxLoggerImpl.java:151)
    at org.ops4j.pax.logging.log4j2.internal.PaxLoggerImpl.doLog(PaxLoggerImpl.java:144)
    at org.ops4j.pax.logging.log4j2.internal.PaxLoggerImpl.error(PaxLoggerImpl.java:192)
    at org.ops4j.pax.logging.internal.TrackingLogger.error(TrackingLogger.java:96)
    at org.ops4j.pax.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLogger.error(Slf4jLogger.java:953)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.support.ShellUtil.logException(ShellUtil.java:152)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.ConsoleSessionImpl.doExecute(ConsoleSessionImpl.java:474)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.ConsoleSessionImpl.run(ConsoleSessionImpl.java:407)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ReflectionUtil not found by org.apache.logging.log4j.api [112]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1639)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$200(BundleWiringImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2053)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.getClassByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1414)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.searchImports(BundleWiringImpl.java:1660)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1590)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$200(BundleWiringImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2053)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 27 more

Comment: Any details? Configuration? Logs? Versions? Steps to reproduce?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the class org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ReflectionUtil no longer exists as of 2.9.0.
i just have to use a version lower than this one